# In Docker, "Error response from daemon: could not choose an IP address to advertise since this system has multiple addresses on different interfaces"

Tags: docker, ip, docker-swarm

My question is similar to [docker swarm init could not choose an IP address error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602903/docker-swarm-init-could-not-choose-an-ip-address-error), but I found the accepted answer somewhat vague so I'll ask again. Upon trying

```
docker swarm init
```

I'm geting an error message

> Error response from daemon: could not choose an IP address to advertise since this system has multiple addresses on different interfaces (192.168.130.117 on enp1s0 and 192.168.130.89 on wlp2s0) - specify one with --advertise-addr

What could be the root cause of this? I'm currently running a VPN (OneClickVPN); is that a problem?

Also, in order to specify one address with `--advertise-addr`, I'd like to find out more about the addresses given in the message. How could I do that?

Comment: `docker swarm init --help` for more info.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It looks like you have two active network interfaces, one on `enp1s0` and another on `wlp2s0`. I'd guess `enp1s0` is an Ethernet connection and `wlp2s0` is a WiFi connection.

As mentioned in the question you linked to, if you have multiple addresses on different interfaces, you have to specify one with `--advertise-addr`. In your case, you're essentially choosing between your Ethernet and WiFi interfaces.

Comment: Yes, the `enp1s0` is an Ethernet address as verified (in Ubuntu) by inspecting System Settings -> Network. `docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.130.117` successfully initialized the swarm.

Answer (score 9):

I used the following command:

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr 127.0.0.1
```

It worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you were doing the following excercise (chapter 2):
https://github.com/docker/labs/blob/master/beginner/chapters/alpine.md
and then you moved to the chapter 3.

In addition to King's answer, you should check your default IP.

```
docker-machine ip default
```

Answer (score 1):

I only wanted to have a small swarm with 1 master node on my work laptop so I can run some tests.
So I did this:

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr 127.0.0.1
```

And it worked just fine for what I needed

Answer (score -3):

That error looks two interface IP are running thats way your interface getting ambiguity, And its very simply to execute take your docker-machine's ip then hit,

Ex: docker swarm init --advertise-addr 111.111.11.111